# Multiple pack files in git on remote machine

Tags: git, azure, pipeline, release

I'm having an issue when using Azure Releases to pull a repo to a remote machine.

When going to the .git/objects/pack folder, I can see multiple pack files (These are currently 5.1gb) - I deleted the repo and re-ran the release and it's still doing it. Before I deleted it I had over 10 of these files.

On the same machine, I also tried putting on SourceTree and using pulling the repo down with this. Both the SourceTree git folder & my local git folders don't contain multiple pack files, but only one.

I've put my Powershell Script that I am using here:

```
$resourcesPath = "`$(ResourcesPath)"
$environment = "`$(EnvironmentShortName)"
$path = Join-Path -Path $resourcesPath -ChildPath $environment

$resourceCommit = (Get-Content -Path "`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/resources/Metropolis-Resources/commit" -First 1).Trim()
$repo = "Metropolis-Resources"
$env:GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR = '2>&1'

Write-Output "Checking out commit: $resourceCommit"

if(-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $path)) 
{
    New-Item -Path $path -ItemType Directory -Force
    $doInit = $true
}

Write-Host "Setting path: $path"
Set-Location -LiteralPath $path

if($doInit)
{
    Write-Host "Init Git for some reason?"
    & git init
    & git remote add origin "https://AzureDevops:`$(System.Accesstoken)@metropolisrpc.visualstudio.com:/Metropolis/_git/$repo"
}
else
{
    & git remote set-url origin "https://AzureDevops:`$(System.Accesstoken)@metropolisrpc.visualstudio.com:/Metropolis/_git/$repo"
}

Write-Host "Resetting head..."
git clean -xdf
git reset --hard

Write-Host "Fetching commit..."
& git fetch origin $resourceCommit

if(-not $doInit)
{
    Write-Host "Generating diff..."
    & git diff HEAD..$resourceCommit --stat
}

& git checkout $resourceCommit
```

Comment: The size of a pack is configurable. `pack.packSizeLimit` in gitconfig affects it. So does `--max-pack-size` in `git repack`. Maybe Azure Releases uses a limit size when creating packs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple `.pack` files are normal.  When using the multi-pack-index feature, they should be quite efficient as well (though they will obviously occupy more space).  Depending on particular circumstances, they could even be *more* efficient than single pack files (though I'd want to measure this before making any solid claims here).

To squash multiple pack files into fewer (or even just one) pack file, use `git repack`, or `git gc` which runs `git repack` for you.  Note that doing this is expensive (in CPU time and energy if nothing else) and if there's little gained by repacking, you've wasted most of this expense.  If a lot is gained, it's worthwhile.

The newfangled [`git maintenance` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance) can be used to schedule `git gc` operations for times when nothing else is going on.

Git normally runs `git gc --auto` on its own, which spins off a background `git gc` whenever Git thinks this would be profitable.